# Range function not iterating whole list, help me pls

Tags: python-3.x, list

```py
def count4(lst):
    count = 0
    for i in range(lst[0],lst[-1]+1):
        print(i)
      

print(count4([1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,4]))
```

Here the output is showing just "1234" and not the whole list pls tell me how to iterate this list using range function.

Comment: `for i in lst: print(i)` or even `print(*lst, sep = '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting output as "1234"

The below statement

```
for i in range(last[0], last[-1]+1):
```

is interpreted as

```
for i in range(1, 4 + 1):
```

i.e

```
for i in range(1,5):
```

Solution: Use this

```
 for i in lst:
```

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to iterate in the range of values stored in the list at starting and end position that was passed, which is logically incorrect.
The other suggested methods are also correct since you specifically said to use the `range` function so think this might be the answer you were looking for

```
def count4(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        print(lst[i])
      
print(count4([1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,4]))
```